# SQL query for finding unique rows based on three parameters - kind of "get first row in sorted grouped set"

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, mysql-5.7

I am trying to see if there is a way using SQL to find a unique grouped row based on three parameters. It is kind of getting the first row of each `group-by` key in a special sorted set.

Note: I am stuck on a mysql 5.7.

This is my test table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE observations (
  id int(10)   AUTO_INCREMENT,
   area_code varchar(5),
   observation_date timestamp,
   reading int(10),
   source varchar(10),
   deleted_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
 );

INSERT INTO observations (area_code,observation_date, reading, source, deleted_at)
 VALUES
 ('test1', '2021-01-01', 7, 'auto', null),
 ('test1', '2021-01-02', 6, 'auto', null),
 ('test1', '2021-01-03', 5, 'auto', null),
 ('test2', '2021-01-01', 7, 'auto', null),
 ('test2', '2021-01-02', 6, 'manual', null),
 ('test2', '2021-01-03', 5, 'auto', null),
 ('test3', '2021-01-01', 7, 'auto', null),
 ('test3', '2021-01-02', 6, 'manual', '2021-01-02'),
 ('test3', '2021-01-03', 5, 'auto', null);
```

`source` is either `auto` or `manual`

There are multiple areas - for each of these I would like to get the latest reading basing on `observation_date`, but only if the `source` is `auto`. If the `source` is `manual` then this will have precedence - and should always the returned as the reading for that area. However, if the `deleted_at` is set (only applies to `manual`) then the `manual` `source` should be ignored - and `observation_date` is again the primary criteria.

So the three parameters are: `observation_date`, `source` and `deleted_at` - everything is kept in order to preserve history.

Here is my current query with actual output and then the expected output:

Current query attempt:

```
SELECT obs1.*
FROM observations AS obs1
LEFT JOIN observations AS obs2 ON
  obs1.area_code = obs2.area_code AND
  obs1.id != obs2.id AND
 NOT ( 
 (obs1.source = "manual" 
  AND obs1.deleted_at IS NULL
   ) 
 OR 
  (obs1.observation_date > obs2.observation_date AND obs2.source = "auto"  )
 )
WHERE obs2.id IS NULL
```

Actual output:

```
id  area_code   observation_date    reading source  deleted_at
3   test1   2021-01-03 00:00:00     5       auto    NULL
5   test2   2021-01-02 00:00:00     6       manual  NULL
```

Actual output (with `AND obs1.deleted_at IS NULL` removed):

```
id  area_code   observation_date    reading source  deleted_at
3   test1   2021-01-03 00:00:00     5       auto    NULL
5   test2   2021-01-02 00:00:00     6       manual  NULL
8   test3   2021-01-02 00:00:00     6       manual  2021-01-02 00:00:00
```

Expected output:

```
id  area_code   observation_date    reading source  deleted_at
3   test1   2021-01-03 00:00:00     5       auto    NULL
5   test2   2021-01-02 00:00:00     6       manual  NULL
8   test3   2021-01-03 00:00:00     5       auto    NULL
```

I have tried many variations of the query - but none have provided the expected result.

Is it even possible - or am I going about it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the expected result should contain id 9, not id 8 as you specified, because id 8 is a manual one that has been deleted.
So the expected result is

```
id  area_code   observation_date    reading source  deleted_at
3   test1   2021-01-03 00:00:00     5       auto    NULL
5   test2   2021-01-02 00:00:00     6       manual  NULL
9   test3   2021-01-03 00:00:00     5       auto    NULL
```

If you run it without the WHERE condition and SELECT the obs2.* rows

```
SELECT obs1.*, obs2.*
FROM observations AS obs1
LEFT JOIN observations AS obs2 ON
  obs1.area_code = obs2.area_code AND
  obs1.id != obs2.id AND
 NOT ( 
 (obs1.source = "manual" 
  AND obs1.deleted_at IS NULL
   ) 
 OR 
  (obs1.observation_date > obs2.observation_date AND obs2.source = "auto"  )
 )
WHERE 1 OR obs2.id IS NULL
```

You will see that the result contains

```
9   test3   2021-01-03T00:00:00Z    5   auto    (null)  8   test3   2021-01-02T00:00:00Z    6   manual  2021-01-02T00:00:00Z
```

So the problem is that you are not taking into consideration `obs2.source = 'manual'`.

```
SELECT obs1.*
FROM observations AS obs1
LEFT JOIN observations AS obs2 ON
  obs1.area_code = obs2.area_code AND
  obs1.id != obs2.id AND
  NOT (
    (obs1.source = "manual" AND obs1.deleted_at IS NULL) OR
    (obs2.source = 'manual' AND obs2.deleted_at IS NOT NULL) OR
    (obs1.observation_date > obs2.observation_date AND obs2.source = "auto")
  )
WHERE obs2.id IS NULL
```

See also http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc675e/13/0

Answer (score 1):

Everything's possible

Let's number the rows according to the logic you gave:

```
SELECT *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY area_code ORDER BY
    CASE 
      WHEN source = 'manual' and deleted_at IS NULL THEN 0 --priority
      WHEN source = 'manual' and deleted_at IS NOT NULL THEN 2 --not priority
      ELSE 1 --auto
    END, 
    observation_date DESC
  ) as rown
FROM
  obervations
```

Then just take the rows with rown=1:

```
WITH cte AS(
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY area_code ORDER BY
      CASE 
        WHEN source = 'manual' and deleted_at IS NULL THEN 0 --priority
       WHEN source = 'manual' and deleted_at IS NOT NULL THEN 2 --not priority
        ELSE 1 --auto
      END, 
      observation_date DESC
    ) as rown
  FROM
    obervations
)
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rown = 1
```

Row number breaks a resultset into groups per unique combination of column(s) sepcified in PARTITION BY and then assigns an incrementing number in order of the ordering clause set in the ORDER BY.

This logic above sorts all your manual obs into lead (0) and deleted manual obs into trailing (2) with autos going in place 1, then the obs date descending (latest) is used as the tie breaker if multiples apply

Comment: Thanks, but I am sorry that I forgot to mention that I am stuck on a mysql 5.7 - so OVER and PARTITION BY is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

This is the type of thing that you do with a correlated subquery in older versions of MySQL:

```
select o.*
from observations o
where o.id = (select o2.id
              from observations o2
              where o2.area_code = o.area_code and
                    o2.deleted_at is null
              order by (o2.source = 'manual') desc,
                       o2.observation_date desc
              limit 1
             );
```